# Safari Issue with Single Page Application AngularJS in HTML5mode with AWS (Cloudfront/S3)

Tags: angularjs, amazon-s3, single-page-application, amazon-cloudfront

I am running an AngularJS application in S3 and served up in a CloudFront distribution. I chose a CloudFront distribution for performance and the simplicity of installing the SSL certificate. The SPA is in HTML5mode to have a clean URL structure.

I configured html5Mode in my app.js file.

```
    .config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');

}]).config(function($locationProvider){
      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  })
```

In my index.html file I set the base tag as follows:

```
<base href="/" />
```

I have an S3 bucket serving up a static website, without any re-direct rules.

[image: S3 bucket rules]

Lastly in my Cloudfront dashboard I set the error response as follows:

[image: cloudfront error response rules]

I did this for 404 and 403 responses. When I attempt open a link to a non root path (/pricing), it works fine in Chrome and Firefox. However, in Safari I get redirected to the root path. Apparently the hash in Safari and ios is not dropped if you are using https protocol.

I am not sure how to resolve the Safari specific issue. If anyone has any experience resolving this issue, I would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: HTML5 mode requires url-rewriting.

Comment: Hi everyone. As a follow up, this original configuration indeed worked. Setting the custom error response worked. It was taking time to cache changes in the  error response settings.