# Safari Issue with Single Page Application React with AWS (Cloudfront/S3)

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, redirect, safari, refresh

I am hosting a single page application based in React in S3 and served up in a CloudFront distribution (AWS). Everything works fine in production and The CloudFront error handling is setup correctly like shown below:

[image: Custom error response settings]

I did this for 404 and 403 responses. When I attempt open a link to a non root path (e.g. /settings), it works fine in Chrome and Firefox. **However, in Safari I get redirected to the root path.** I don't know how to resolve this Safari specific issue, any help is appreciated, thank you.

Similar problem without an answer here [Safari Issue with Single Page Application AngularJS in HTML5mode with AWS (Cloudfront/S3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50649588/safari-issue-with-single-page-application-angularjs-in-html5mode-with-aws-cloud)

Comment: Try clearing the cache.

Comment: I cleared the browser cache: same results. Are you talking about the cache for CloudFront?

Comment: The problem stays the same after clearing browser cache and invalidating CloudFront files.